# Differential formula for polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial whose degree  is $m$. I want to show that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}(-1)^{m-j}g(x+jh)}{h^m}=\frac{d^m}{dx}g(x).$$
My idea is to proceed by induction on $m$. The formula holds trivially for $m=1$. Assume we have the equation for $m$. Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial with degree $m+1$. We have to show
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{j}(-1)^{m+1-j}g(x+jh)}{h^{m+1}}=\frac{d^{m+1}}{dx}g(x).$$
I tried to expand the numerator using the identity $\binom{m+1}{j}=\binom{m}{j}+\binom{m}{j-1}$ but that got me nowhere. It's not obvious to me how I can utilize the inductive hypothesis. Maybe a proof by induction is not the right approach?

Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: It seems related to Newton divided differences with points $x, x + h, \dots, x + mh$.

Comment: More to the point, the expression in the limit is $\frac{(\tau_h - I)^m}{h^m}g(x) = (\frac{\tau_h - I}{h})^mg(x)$, where $\tau_hf(x) = f(x + h)$. So it's literally taking a difference quotient $m$ times.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau_h$ be the operator on functions defined by $\tau_hf(x) = f(x + h)$. The key insight is that the binomial formula applies to the sum:
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{m}\binom{m}{j}(-1)^{m - j}\tau_h^jg(x) = (\tau_h - I)^mg(x).$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: But how do you take the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}(\tau_h-I)^mg(x)$?

Comment: @Vab22 Don't forget the $h^m$ in the denominator. Does $\frac{\tau_h - I}{h}g(x) = \frac{g(x + h) - g(x)}{h}$ look familiar to you? Recall that by the mean value theorem, there exists $\theta \in (0, 1)$ such that $\frac{g(x + h) - g(x)}{h} = g'(x + \theta h)$.

Comment: Thank you, I see. This shows that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(\tau_h-I)}{h}g(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}g'(x+\theta_hh)=g'(x)$, right?--but how do you take care of the case $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(\tau_h-I)^m}{h}g(x)$? Is it by induction? In that case,$ \frac{(\tau_h-I)^2}{h}g(x)=\frac{g(x+2h)-2g(x+h)+g(x)}{h}$. To what do we apply mean value theorem in this case?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write $h^m$ and $h^2$, respectively, in my previous comment.

Comment: @Vab22 Use $\frac{(\tau_h - I)^m}{h^m} = (\frac{\tau_h - I}{h})^m$ and use the mean value theorem $m$ times.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try checking that the identity is valid for a basis of polynomials, e.g monomials such as $1,x^2, 
\ldots, x^m$, then use linearity of limits to establish it for linear combinations.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps. I'm stuck at the induction step..Are you sure this works?